# Converting a json object to a table in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have the following JSON stored with redux. This json includes assessment criteria (i.e., `rubricItems`), and per each criterion, the scores assigned by different users.

```
rubricItems: {
    '1': {
    id: 1,
    title: 'The code properly uses the loops to minimize hard-coding.',
    currentScores: [
      {
        id: 7,
        score: 5,
        evaluatorName: 'Chauncey Agar',            
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        score: 4,
        evaluatorName: 'Danial Dagar',            
      }
    ]
  },
  '2': {
    id: 2,
    title: 'The code properly uses functions to reduce repetition and complexity.',
    currentScores: [
      {
        id: 3,
        score: 2,            
        evaluatorName: 'Mike James',
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        score: 2,
        evaluatorName: 'Chauncey Agar',            
      }
    ]
  },
```

What I want to achieve is shown below:

```
  Rubric items                                                  Chauncey Agar | Danial Dagar  |  Mike James
  The code properly uses the loops to minimize hard-coding.          5              4            0     
  The code properly uses functions to reduce repetition.             2              -            2
```

However, I have no clue about how I can achieve this in react. I believe using some npm packages may help. Any ideas or hints to help me make some progress with this?

Comment: I do not know of any modules but you can convert your data to an array and use .map. It is definitely doable with a little complex algo without using any packages.

Comment: For the first element, you don't have an evaluator named "Mike James" so you put the score as 0. For the second element, you don't have an evaluator named "Danial Dagar" so you put the score as a -. You should keep it consistent

Comment: Asking for package recommendations is off-topic, and I don't see an attempt to accomplish it yourself. Could you edit the question to be on-topic including what you've tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: After getting the data I would first create an array which stores all possible evaluator names. Meaning I travers all `currentScores` and add only new entries if there are not already in that array.
After that I would construct a table in a loop over `rubricItems` for each ID and add for each evaluaterName the corresponding score and add a "0" or "-" for all remaining names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const rubricItems = {
    '1': {
      id: 1,
      title: 'The code properly uses the loops to minimize hard-coding.',
      currentScores: [
        {
          id: 7,
          score: 5,
          evaluatorName: 'Chauncey Agar'
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          score: 4,
          evaluatorName: 'Danial Dagar'
        }
      ]
    },
    '2': {
      id: 2,
      title:
        'The code properly uses functions to reduce repetition and complexity.',
      currentScores: [
        {
          id: 3,
          score: 2,
          evaluatorName: 'Mike James'
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          score: 2,
          evaluatorName: 'Chauncey Agar'
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  const scores = {};
  const evaluators = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(rubricItems);
  keys.forEach((key, i) => {
    rubricItems[key].currentScores.forEach(({ evaluatorName, score }) => {
      if (!evaluators.includes(evaluatorName)) {
        evaluators.push(evaluatorName);
      }
      if (scores[key]) {
        scores[key] = {
          ...scores[key],
          [evaluatorName]: score
        };
      } else {
        scores[key] = {
          [evaluatorName]: score
        };
      }
    });
  });

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th />
          {evaluators.map(evaluator => (
            <th>{evaluator}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {keys.map(key => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{rubricItems[key].title}</td>
              {evaluators.map(evaluator => {
                const score = scores[key][evaluator];
                return <td>{score ? score : '-'}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

You can check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1msm31